# Sturm-Liouville problem with regular-singular point in the interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, spectral-theory, eigenfunctions, differential-operators, sturm-liouville

I am confronted with an eigenvalue problem on $\mathbb{R}$ whose differential equation has a regular-singular point at $x=0$. For that reason, I am interested to know if there are known results or general theory of Sturm-Liouville problems
$$
(p(x)y(x)')'+q(x)y(x)=\lambda\sigma(x) y(x),\;\;x\in\mathbb{R}, \;\;\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}y=0,
$$
where the ODE has a regular-singular point for some value of $x$. The classical Sturm-Liouville theory assumptions imply that there are no singular points on the interval of interest.  Above, for the sake of example, I took the reals as the interval, together with vanishing boundary conditions. However, if results concerning finite intervals and/or other types of boundary conditions exist, I would be interested. I would also be interested if results would exist for non self-adjoint problems (i.e. not necessarily restricted to the Sturm-Liouville type).

Comment: The conditions at $\pm\infty$ may not make sense. For example, the singular problem $y''=\lambda y$ does not have solutions that vanish at $\pm\infty$, regardless of the $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$. Then, if you allow for a finite singular point, you may need some type of condition at that point. Non self-adjoint problems do not generally give rise to coherent eigenvalue problems.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Depending of the interval of interest, there are conditions on $p$, $q$, and $\sigma$ to make the S-L problem regular (see Zettl, 2005).  In your case, $p=\sigma=1$ don't satisfy those conditions on $\mathbb{R}$. Having $\mathbb{R}$ as the interval is not important to me. What I am interested in is the effect of having a r-s point on the interval. I like the point you raise: the condition I can think of is I want the eigenvector to be in $L^2$. For example, if the solution behaves as $1/x^2$ at the r-s point, then it cannot be a candidate for an eigenvector.

Comment: What do you mean by a regular problem on $\mathbb{R}$. That's not terminology I've heard in that regard. Also, a regular singular point is something I've only heard in the context of analytic coefficients. Perhaps you can point to the pages where you are looking.

Comment: By regular-singular point I just mean that the differential equation has a such a point on the interval. Regular-singular points are defined in the context of the Frobenius method.

Comment: That's what I thought you meant. I don't believe that a regular singular point is going to dictate the existence of non-zero point functionals, for example. Does it?